# Can't find include lib "rabbit_common/include/rabbit.hrl" in cowboy

Tags: erlang, cowboy

Trying to run tutorial samples for RabbitMQ in Erlang under OSX but it fails with the following message:

```
./send.erl:20: can't find include lib "rabbit_common/include/rabbit.hrl"
./send.erl:21: can't find include lib "rabbit_common/include/rabbit_framing.hrl"
escript: There were compilation errors.
```

amqp_example.erl:

```
-module(amqp_example).

-include("amqp_client.hrl").

-compile([export_all]).

test() ->
    %% Start a network connection
    {ok, Connection} = amqp_connection:start(#amqp_params_network{}),
    %% Open a channel on the connection
    {ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),

    %% Declare a queue
    #'queue.declare_ok'{queue = Q}
        = amqp_channel:call(Channel, #'queue.declare'{}),
    %% Publish a message
    Payload = <<"foobar">>,
    Publish = #'basic.publish'{exchange = <<>>, routing_key = Q},
    amqp_channel:cast(Channel, Publish, #amqp_msg{payload = Payload}),

    %% Get the message back from the queue
    Get = #'basic.get'{queue = Q},
    {#'basic.get_ok'{delivery_tag = Tag}, Content}
         = amqp_channel:call(Channel, Get),

    %% Do something with the message payload
    %% (some work here)

    %% Ack the message
    amqp_channel:cast(Channel, #'basic.ack'{delivery_tag = Tag}),

    %% Close the channel
    amqp_channel:close(Channel),
    %% Close the connection
    amqp_connection:close(Connection),

    ok.
```

Please help me to fix this problem. Thank!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erlang has macro `include_lib`, which can search for libraries in path and is convenient, because you don't have to specify version of library - it automatically uses newest version. So, instead of

```
-include("rabbit_common-3.3.5/include/rabbit.hrl").
```

you can just write:

```
-include_lib("rabbit_common/include/rabbit.hrl").
```

So, in your case, you have to make sure, that file `rabbit_common-[version]/include/rabbit.hrl` is in `ERL_LIBS` path. In the [tutorial, you are using](https://www.rabbitmq.com/erlang-client-user-guide.html), they want you to download those files from [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/erlang-client-user-guide.html) and unpack them like this:

```
unzip -d deps deps/amqp_client.ez
unzip -d deps deps/rabbit_common.ez
```

Those unpacking commands *do not* work on OS X, because unzip works only with .zip files. So this might be your problem. Try using another application to unpack them and double check, that the file is there. Don't forget to add `ERL_LIBS=deps` before compiling and running the example:

```
ERL_LIBS=deps erlc -o ebin amqp_example.erl
ERL_LIBS=deps erl -pa ebin
```

Comment: Hello @tkowal, How can I add file rabbit_common-[version]/include/rabbit.hrl in ERL_LIBS path?

Comment: You have to add deps directory by prepending `ERL_LIBS=deps` before your command. Then, if you have `deps/rabbit_common-3.3.5/include/rabbit.hrl` file unpacked, it will find it.

Comment: Thank for your helpul @tkowal, It is working now. :)